# Can I add /dev/sda1 after I accidentally deleted?

Tags: gparted

After I deleted /dev/sda1 I expected to be able afterward to reclaim the unallocated space. Did not happen and please someone to clarify why.

The unallocated space to create a new partition is not shown in GParted
From live USB GParted does not have unallocated space either. Where 1MB disappeared?

Here EFI partition **unused** 0.00B
[image]

This is from live USB still not seen the 1007Kb deleted.
[image]

Here EFI partition **unused** 59.45Mib. Why?
[image]

If I will add /dev/sda1 this will be with a new UUID, so the kernel is still looking for old UUID? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Using fdisk,

1. `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`
2. `n` create new partition
3. press enter for first sector
4. add desired space using `+#K` or `+#M` or `+#G`

   example `+256M` adds 256 megabytes

Comment: before I deleted /dev/sda1 I had 1Mb unallocated space. After I deleted /dev/sda1 I should have 1Mb plus 1007Kb from deleted /dev/sda1, but I only have 1Mb unallocated space. Where 1007kb dissapeared?